# How do I upload my pandas dataframe to already existing report in salesforce

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, salesforce, simple-salesforce, beatbox

I'm new to working with salesforce, but I have a pandas dataframe with me and I also have an existing salesforce report, I'd like to export my pandas dataframe to my salesforce report.

I looked into many examples and the documentation itself but I didn't really find what I was looking for.

Any code & help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You want something that creates/updates a Salesforce report based on Python one? There's REST-based analytics api (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_analytics.meta/api_analytics/analytics_api_report_example_post_report.htm) but you'd have to translate the report yourself and it might not be possible to 100% recreate it in SF.

If you have some heavy processing in Python it might be better idea to upload the calculation results back to SF and run report on them. Nightly job to clear and reload a helper table.